# Is it possible to remove 'Allow Once' from location authorization request?

Tags: react-native, permissions, geolocation

I am developing a React Native application that uses maps and location permissions. I want user to select just "Allow while using app" or "Don't Allow" options. But it shows me the "Allow once" option as well.

[image]

Here is my Info.plist file edits;

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Fenomen Air Sports wants permission to be able to record your flights</string>
```

It is ok if I don't use `NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription` and `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` in location settings, so it does not show Always Allow option here;

[image]

Can I remove the "Allow Once" option from the permission request if it is possible?

I also checked some sources;

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/choosing_the_location_services_authorization_to_request
- https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-geolocation/issues/863
- https://medium.com/@transistorsoft/ios-13-and-android-q-support-beb7595d2c24

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you ever manage to find an answer to this?

Comment: I stopped working on that project and do not remember, unfortunately.